# Read bytes from user selected media file Android Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

#### **Tested with 34 API**

#### Task

I need to take a photo from the user and send it to the server

#### My solution

1. I ask the user for a photo from his gallery via Compose `ActivityResultContracts.PickMultipleVisualMedia`:

```
val photoPicker = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
    contract = ActivityResultContracts.PickMultipleVisualMedia(12)
) { photos ->
    photos.takeIf { it.isNotEmpty() }?.let { uri ->
        dispatch(Action.OnClickUploadImages(uri.map { it.toString() }))
    }
}
```

2. Next I save the list of uri in `ViewModel` to show on screen via `Coil` (it works fine)
3. And when the user clicks on the submit button I send it to the server:

```
private fun sendImages() = viewModelScope.launch {
    useCases.sendImagesUseCase(_state.value.images)
}
```

4. And then I'm trying to get bytes from the file system via the images URI:

```
override suspend fun getFile(uri: String): ByteArray = withContext(coroutineContext) {
    File(Uri.parse(uri).path).readBytes()
}
```

At this step app crashing with exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /picker/0/com.android.providers.media.photopicker/media/1000003737: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

I tried add permissions to the `Manifest`, but it's still not works:

- `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`
- `READ_MEDIA_IMAGES`
- `READ_MEDIA_VISUAL_USER_SELECTED`

### Question

How can I correctly get the bytes of an image from the filesystem given only its uri?

Comment: Use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` on the content identified by the `Uri`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**@CommonsWare** helped me find the right solution to my problem

The solution is based on ContentResolver:

```kotlin
override suspend fun getFile(uri: String): ByteArray = withContext(coroutineContext) {
    context.contentResolver.openInputStream(Uri.parse(uri))?.let {
        val bytes = it.readBytes()
        it.close()
        bytes
    } ?: byteArrayOf()
}
```